# DependsOn vs links - docker-compose vs ECS task

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, docker-container

[DependsOn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions.html#cfn-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinition-dependson)

property of ECS container definition is used for container dependencies

[Links](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#links) property of docker compose  provides service dependencies.

---

We are mapping a docker compose file to ECS task definition.

Conceptually, Is the purpose of `links` property in docker compose  similar to `DependsOn` property of ECS container definition?

Comment: @DavidMaze can you also comment on this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/60676301/3317808

Answer (score 1):

[`links:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links) was an important part of the first-generation Docker networking setup.  Once Docker introduced the `docker network` series of commands and Docker Compose set up a private network by default, it became much less important, and there's not really any reason to use it at all in modern Docker.

Compose has its own [`depends_on:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on) option.  If service `a` `depends_on: [b]`, then when `a` starts up (maybe because you explicitly `docker-compose up a`, or maybe just as an ordering constraint) the `b` container is guaranteed to exist.  If `b` is a database or some other service that takes a while to start up, it's not guaranteed to be *functional*, but for instance `b` will be a valid host name from `a`'s point of view.

Within a single ECS task, one container can [`dependsOn`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_dependson) others.  This is similar to the Compose `depends_on:` setting, but it has an additional `condition` parameter that can support a couple of different lifecycles.  Of note, one container can wait for another to be `"condition": "HEALTHY"`, a check that in Docker Compose requires the waiting container to manually check on its own (ofter with a helper script like `wait-for-it.sh`); it can also wait for another container to `"condition": "COMPLETE"` if one container just does setup for another.

If you're porting a Docker Compose file to an ECS task, I'd start by trying to replace `links:` with `depends_on:`, which shouldn't cause much functional change; translating this to ECS, the semantics of that are very similar to `"dependsOn": [{"condition": "START"}]`.

Comment: Yes am porting docker compose to ECS task

Comment: I don't believe this translation is supported by `docker compose`

https://github.com/docker/compose-cli/issues/2166